# Precision getting lost when transforming the PCL pointcloud

Tags: matrix, point-cloud-library, coordinate-transformation, lidar

I am using the [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/matrix_transform.php) from PCL to transform the point cloud I have. Basically, I am only translating the cloud by some offset.

The problem is I am losing the precision after applying this transformation. More clear in the figure below.

I see that this only happens when I have large values(>6 digits) for my offset, by which the cloud is getting translated.

Below is the code which makes use of the pcl library

```
 Eigen::Matrix4d translationMatrix = Eigen::Matrix4d::Identity();

 //translation
 translationMatrix(0,3) = 1000000;
 translationMatrix(1,3) = 1000000;

 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr translatedCloud;
 translatedCloud.reset(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());

 pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud,*translatedCloud,translationMatrix);

 pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII ("translatedCloud.pcd",*translatedCloud);
```

original cloud

[image: original cloud]

transformed cloud

[image: transformed cloud]

I suspect the problem might be the range of the data type being used.

Any information on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the range of offset being used. The pcl::PointXYZ has points as the floats,so when providing such offsets out of range, it would round off the result, which was causing the loss in precision. One obvious solution to this is to normalize the range if possible. Another solution is to add a custom point type in PCL. There is a nice [document](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php) about this provided by the PCL.

Comment: New link for custom point type documentation.
https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **PCDWriter** class directly with precision input.

As suggested, created a custom point type in PCL and saved in ASCII. Only the ASCII format had this precision input. Don't know about other formats.

**NOTE:** For this new double type custom pointcloud, the available PCL tools won't work, since PCL uses float.
For more info: [Link](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1953)

Comment: I also tried to use the code at the link above and found that PCL in general cannot handle a custom point cloud with double precision storage.  The first thing I found was that transforms don't work.  There is probably a lot of other components that don't work.  I instead converted my data to single precision floating point representation by subtracting off the mean.